# moderncv class: prevent indentation in address section after making it left-justified

Tags: indentation, moderncv

I am using the moderncv class (http://www.ctan.org/pkg/moderncv) to write my CV. In order to modify the address section, I modified moderncvstyleclassic.sty.

I want to get the text of the address section left-justified (which worked), but now I have the problem that the first line of the address (addressstreet) is indented.

My question is: How do I prevent this indentation of the first line within this information box

So far I did not find any solutions for this problem.

Code in **moderncvstyleclassic.sty** with my change commented:

```
%% code above omitted
      % optional detailed information box
      \newbox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}%
      \savebox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}{%
        \addressfont\color{color2}%
        \begin{tabular}[b]{@{}l@{}}%% MY MODIFICATION <<-- l for left-justified (instead of "r")
          \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreet}}{}{\makenewline\@addressstreet%\addresssymbol##
            \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscity}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscity}}% if \addresstreet is defined, \addresscity will always be defined but could be empty
            \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@countryinfo}}{}{\makenewline\@countryinfo}%%##moved up to use as country
          \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@mobile}}{}{\makenewline\mobilesymbol\@mobile}%
          \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@phone}}{}{\makenewline\phonesymbol\@phone}%
          \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@fax}}{}{\makenewline\faxsymbol\@fax}%
          \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@email}}{}{\makenewline\emailsymbol\emaillink{\@email}}%
          \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@homepage}}{}{%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\@homepagetitle}{}}% \homepagetitle could be empty
        {\makenewline\homepagesymbol\httplink{\@homepage}}%
        {\makenewline\homepagesymbol\httplink[\@homepagetitle]{\@homepage}}}% 
          \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@extrainfo}}{}{\makenewline\@extrainfo}%##moved up to use as country
        \end{tabular}
      }% 
      %% code below omitted
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the `\patchcmd` macro:

```
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\makecvtitle}{@{}r@{}}{@{}l@{}}{}{}
\patchcmd{\makecvtitle}{\makenewline\addresssymbol\@addressstreet}{\addresssymbol\@addressstreet\makenewline}{}{}
\makeatother
```

after the style declaration.

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Or if you want to manually edit the .sty file (discouraged) just change from:

```
\makenewline\addresssymbol\@addressstreet
```

to:

```
\addresssymbol\@addressstreet\makenewline
```

For also putting the extrainfo below city use the following set of commands instead of the previous:

```
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\makecvtitle}{@{}r@{}}{@{}l@{}}{}{}
\patchcmd{\makecvtitle}{\makenewline\addresssymbol\@addressstreet}{\addresssymbol\@addressstreet\makenewline}{}{}
\patchcmd{\makecvtitle}{\makenewline\@extrainfo}{}{}{}
\patchcmd{\makecvtitle}{\ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscountry}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscountry}}{\ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscountry}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscountry}\makenewline\@extrainfo}{}{}
\makeatother
```

result:

[image]

the `country` field is optional, if you set the `address` like this:

```
\address{street and number}{postcode city}{country}
```

you'll have a country. Otherwise, like this:

```
\address{street and number}{postcode city}
```

you'll have no country (as in my last picture).

### Complete MWE

```
  \documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{classic}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\makecvtitle}{@{}r@{}}{@{}l@{}}{}{}
\patchcmd{\makecvtitle}{\makenewline\addresssymbol\@addressstreet}{\addresssymbol\@addressstreet\makenewline}{}{}
\patchcmd{\makecvtitle}{\makenewline\@extrainfo}{}{}{}
\patchcmd{\makecvtitle}{\ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscountry}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscountry}}{\ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscountry}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscountry}\makenewline\@extrainfo}{}{}
\makeatother

\moderncvcolor{blue}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

% personal data
\name{John}{Doe}
\title{Resumé title}
\address{street and number}{postcode city}{country}
\phone[mobile]{+1~(234)~567~890}                   
\phone[fixed]{+2~(345)~678~901}
\phone[fax]{+3~(456)~789~012}
\email{john@doe.org}                               
\homepage{www.johndoe.com}                         
\social[linkedin]{john.doe}                        
\social[twitter]{jdoe}                             
\social[github]{jdoe}                              
\extrainfo{additional information}                 
\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{picture}                       
\quote{Some quote}                                 

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle

\section{Education}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}
\end{document}
```

Comment: First solution works! Related Question: How do I alter the position of the "additional information" line without altering the .sty file?

Comment: @HTS where do you want to put it?

Comment: below city. I want to use it as an information for "country". My version of moderncv ( Version 1.11 (19/6/14)) seems to miss the "country" option in the \address{Street}{City} command. Using \address{Street}{City}{Country} throws an error. Editing the .sty file is an option which I would like to avoid.

Comment: @HTS see the edit.

Comment: the proposed newest solutions for "country" or the "additional information" did not work for me. Using \address{Street}{City}{Country} throws an error and the "additional information" does not show up. In your first code example "additional information" can be seen.

Comment: @HTS I'm attaching a complete CV so that you just need to copy-paste it in a new document, compile and see that it works as expected.

Comment: compiling your last example throws several errors in my setting ("undefined control sequence" l.15 \name). Are you using moderncv ( Version 1.11 (19/6/14))? Otherwise there might be a problem hidden in my installation of LaTex (OS X 10.5.8; (TeX Live 2013/MacPorts 2013_5))

Comment: @HTS Tex Live 2014 here and the moderncv.cls file says it's version 1.5.1 (also please note that you may need to comment out the line `\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{picture}` if you don't have a dummy `picture` in your build directory.

Comment: I updated to Tex Live 2014 and your code still throws several errors. I solved the problem of a missing "country" field by modifying the .cls and .sty files. Using that parts of your code I now have solved the problem.

Comment: @HTS I have no idea, it works fine here. Anyway, as long as you solved you problem it's ok.